# Python Adding objects to a collection

Tags: python

I'm new to python and having trouble with this part. I have a class called Pet and a class named Dogs. I need Pets to declare a collection to hold the various dogs to be added to a list, tuple,or dictionary either one thats easier. For instance

```
pitbull=Dog()
shepard=Dog()
guard_dog=Dog()

animal=Pet()
```

I don't know if python allows objects to be stored in list.In java I can simply store them in a arrayList. Like `pet=arrayList<Dog>()`. I've search around and don't know how to add the Dog objects to a list, tuple,or dictionary in python.Please help anyone

Comment: And the python tutorial didn't help you there either? This is rather basic stuff, really.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Plus in Python you have the shell to try these sorts of things out.

Answer (score 1):

as said Martijn Pieters you should look the python tutorial

for example using a list

```
pitbull=Dog()
shepard=Dog()
guard_dog=Dog()

animal=Pet()

animals = [pitbull,shepard,guard_dog]
animals.append(animal)

#do what ever you want with the list
```